# Redefinition in C

Tags: c

can somebody explain me about redefinition in C:

is it possible to do something like this

```
typedef struct NumberContainer* ptrNumberContainer;
```

and after that

```
  typedef struct NumberContainer* ptrCall;
```

may it cause some problems during linkage? thanks in advance

Comment: Please note this has nothing whatsoever to do with eclipse - I've removed the tag - again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's perfectly OK - you have two synonyms for the same underlying type - this is quite common. However, the practice of hiding the fact that something is a pointer by using a typedef is generally viewed as bad practice in C.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible. Defines two different type names to mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not redefinition. Redefinition refers to macro definitions:

```
#define FOOBAR 1
#undef FOOBAR
#define FOOBAR 2
```

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I didn't explain it correctly but Neil Butterworth understood what I mean

Comment: can You also give your explanation?

Comment: @Marcelo Surely you can also have errors redefining struct, functions etc?

Comment: After an initial misreading, I did understand what you were asking, and the current answer reflects this. As the other answers point out, what are you doing is legal. What I was pointing out is that you are not actually redefining anything (you cannot redefine symbols in C). I was also trying to suggest where you might have gotten the expression from.

Comment: Just to clarify, you cannot redefine _compiler_ symbols. You can of course redefine macro symbols, which was the point I was making.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, Neil. You will certainly have errors, since, in general, you can't redefine such things at all. I was merely observing that what the OP was doing doesn't go by the name "redefinition".

Answer (score 0):

In that case, `ptrCall` will actually refer to the same type as `ptrNumberContainer`. I think they will also be compatible compile time. So you can say, for example:

```
ptrNumberContainer p1;
ptrCall p2;
```

Then these will work:

```
p1 = p2;
*p1 = *p2;
```